# MAPI - Find file containing MAPI URL (or open message)

Tags: winapi, mapi

I'm using Windows Search API, which returns mapi URLs.

1. How can I find the file which contains the data for the URL? E.g. the path to the PST file from which that message came?
2. How can I programatically get the contents or data of the MAPI message (i.e. as opposed to just opening it up with the shell).

Answer (score 0):

Usually MAPI allow you to invoke a method that retrieves a IMAPITable associated to an object and then sets its columns accordingly to the properties you want to query
check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raffael/archive/2008/09/08/mapi-on-windows-mobile-6-programmatically-retrieve-mail-body-sample-code.aspx) out
]